# DS_Store files crashing Minecraft forge

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, minecraft

I am trying to make a smimple mod in eclipse on macOS, everything worked fine up until I add the texture .png file to the game, then I get a DS_Store error, I have look at almost every fourm about this issue and nothing has worked, I understand that you can stop the creating of a DS_Store on a NAS but not locally, is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
[m[32m[23:15:59] [Forge Version Check/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: [forge] Found status: BETA Current: 30.0.51 Target: 30.0.51
[m[32m[23:15:59] [Forge Version Check/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: [testmod] Starting version check at http://myurl.me/
[m[33m[23:16:00] [Forge Version Check/WARN] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: Failed to process update information
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://myurl.me/
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1950) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1945) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1944) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1514) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.VersionChecker$1.openUrlStream(VersionChecker.java:189) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.VersionChecker$1.process(VersionChecker.java:206) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) [?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.VersionChecker$1.run(VersionChecker.java:157) [?:?] {re:classloading}
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://myurl.me/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.VersionChecker$1.openUrlStream(VersionChecker.java:173) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    ... 3 more
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.cl.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:forge for mod file /Users/bennybergle/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/minecraft_user_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3/forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.cl.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:testmod for mod file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/bin/main
[m[32m[23:16:00] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/SimpleReloadableResourceManager]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, Mod Resources
[m[33m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-7/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Exception loading blockstate definition: minecraft:blockstates/magenta_concrete_powder.json: java.io.FileNotFoundException: minecraft:blockstates/magenta_concrete_powder.json
[m[33m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-7/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Exception loading blockstate definition: 'minecraft:blockstates/magenta_concrete_powder.json' missing model for variant: 'minecraft:magenta_concrete_powder#'
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type CLIENT
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading config file type CLIENT at forge-client.toml for forge
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Built TOML config for /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Loaded TOML config file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Watching TOML config file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml for changes
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeConfig/FORGEMOD]: Loaded forge config file forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type COMMON
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ModList/LOADING]: Dispatching parallel event LifecycleEvent:COMMON_SETUP
[m[36m[23:16:00] [Server-Worker-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ModList/LOADING]: Dispatching parallel event LifecycleEvent:SIDED_SETUP
[m[32m[23:16:02] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Caught error loading resourcepacks, removing all selected resourcepacks
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocationException: Non [a-z0-9_.-] character in namespace of location: .DS_Store:sounds.json
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
Caused by: net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocationException: Non [a-z0-9_.-] character in namespace of location: .DS_Store:sounds.json
    at net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation.<init>(ResourceLocation.java:28) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation.<init>(ResourceLocation.java:39) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.audio.SoundHandler.prepare(SoundHandler.java:71) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.audio.SoundHandler.prepare(SoundHandler.java:35) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.ReloadListener.lambda$reload$0(ReloadListener.java:12) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    ... 5 more
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.cl.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:forge for mod file /Users/bennybergle/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/minecraft_user_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3/forge-1.15.1-30.0.51_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.cl.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:testmod for mod file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/bin/main
[m[32m[23:16:04] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/SimpleReloadableResourceManager]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, Mod Resources
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type CLIENT
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading config file type CLIENT at forge-client.toml for forge
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Built TOML config for /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Loaded TOML config file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Watching TOML config file /Users/bennybergle/Desktop/Mods/Test/run/config/forge-client.toml for changes
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeConfig/FORGEMOD]: Loaded forge config file forge-client.toml
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type COMMON
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ModList/LOADING]: Dispatching parallel event LifecycleEvent:COMMON_SETUP
[m[36m[23:16:04] [Server-Worker-6/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ModList/LOADING]: Dispatching parallel event LifecycleEvent:SIDED_SETUP
[m[32m[23:16:05] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Caught error loading resourcepacks, removing all selected resourcepacks
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocationException: Non [a-z0-9_.-] character in namespace of location: .DS_Store:sounds.json
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
Caused by: net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocationException: Non [a-z0-9_.-] character in namespace of location: .DS_Store:sounds.json
    at net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation.<init>(ResourceLocation.java:28) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation.<init>(ResourceLocation.java:39) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.audio.SoundHandler.prepare(SoundHandler.java:71) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.audio.SoundHandler.prepare(SoundHandler.java:35) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.ReloadListener.lambda$reload$0(ReloadListener.java:12) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[?:1.8.0_231] {}
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: These files are created by Finder, if you don't look at a directory with Finder they aren't created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue when developing for Minecraft on macOS with Eclipse. Try either of these two workarounds I found:

1. [Do `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete` in your mod's directory](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/71201-1132-weird-mod-crashing-phenomenon-still-not-solved/page/2/?tab=comments#comment-379232)
2. [Clean the project in Eclipse before running it](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/76639-solved-rendering-overlay-crash-when-adding-a-block/?tab=comments#comment-367738)